# Create Attribute of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function add() {
  var e_type = document.createElement("p");

  var p_type = document.getElementById("self");

  var text = document.createTextNode("I am a slow walker, but I never walk back.");

  e_type.appendChild(text);

  p_type.appendChild(e_type);

  var pattribute = document.createAttribute("id");

  pattribute.value = "test";

  element.setAttributeNode(pattribute);
}
```

```css
#test {
  color: blue;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="self">

  <p>Hello, Thought of the Day</p>

</div>

<button onclick="add()">Click me</button>
```

:- Added element text color is not changing by the use of createAttribute but
   rest of the tag are changing their color which are using this ID(test).

Comment: whts that element.setAttributeNode(pattribute); element here ?

Comment: what @gayathri said. Also you can use `setAttribute('name', 'value')` instead.

Comment: createElement of type "p" :- var e_type = document.createElement("p");  and its textElement :- var text = document.createTextNode("I am a slow walker, but I never walk back.");

Comment: element is not defined

Comment: I've updated your code to be a runnable snippet in the browser - note how it displays the error when you run the code.  If you open your browser dev tools (usually F12), you will similarly be able to see these errors in your own pages while you're developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element.setAttributeNode(pattribute);
```

is wrong

if you want to style the new p make it

```
e_type.setAttributeNode(pattribute);
```

if you need to style them both

```
p_type.setAttributeNode(pattribute);
```

Comment: ** Thanks @eltonkamami **

Answer (score 1):

refere this becuase your question element is not defined https://plnkr.co/edit/FmaXvsWdVFT7mSB3whxs?p=preview

i changed to

```
 e_type.setAttributeNode(pattribute);
```